# How do I filter document library with url?

Tags: document-library, filter

I'm attempting to filter a document library using the url

I've attempted to do so using this

```
mydomain.com/it/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?Filterfield1=name&filtervalue1=retirement
```

But this address does not filter any of the results.

Comment: I don't believe you can filter on the file name

Comment: @Eric is correct. You can not filter a library by Name. You might be able to do the same thing by creating a new column and having a workflow update the column with the name. Then filter by the new column.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize the "Additional Filters" of the content query webpart, and use the following string for matches to the column you want to match on :
[PageQueryString:filtervalue1]

Comment: I created a content search web part and added the query `path:"mydomain/it"  (FileExtension:doc OR FileExtension:docx OR FileExtension:xls OR FileExtension:xlsx OR FileExtension:ppt OR FileExtension:pptx OR FileExtension:pdf) (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem") Title:{QueryString.MyParameter1}` where it was supposed to grab Title from the parameter in the url. I then used `mydomain.com/it/SitePages/Document%20Search.aspx?FilterField1=MyParameter1&FilterValue1=retirement` but that gave me no results

Comment: Side note, I saw that you can grab a filter from a field on the page rather than the url (which would actually resolve my problem as well) but I'm not sure how to create a field for it refer to.

Comment: My solution is for SharePoint 2010.  I assume you are using 2013?  Sorry I was unaware (please tag questions appropriately), and can't be of help for that one sorry!